# Marketing Cloud - Changing the Status of a Mobile Push Android App

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilesdk, mobilepush-android, certificates

We have an android app with a status of expired because we unintentionally uploaded an Apple APNS cert to the app, and now that has expired.  Is there a way to change the status to active without adding another APNS cert or creating another app?

Our team opened a ticket with Salesforce and instructed us to post this question on Stackexchange as they are unsure.

Comment: Luke, would you mind sharing your support case number with me please?  I'd like to review the case and see where the process broke down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APNS certificate should not affect the normal operation of your application in the Marketing Cloud as it pertains to Android as long as your FCM key is valid.

Also, I am sorry that you were directed here for support.  This should not be the case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we've tested the Android app and are able to send pushes.  We're banking that when SF transitions to .p8 certs this month the expired status will go away.